# Problem with Session Scope while using with Java Bean

Tags: jsp

### FIRST.JSP

```
<jsp:useBean id="Bean" scope="session" class="Bean.Student_Enrollment_Bean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="Bean" property="*"/>

<tr>
    <td >Student First Name</td>
    <td>
    <% if( (Bean.getStudent_first_name()==null) || (Bean.getStudent_first_name().trim().length()==0) || Bean.getStudent_first_name().equals("null"))  {  %>
        <input type="text" name="student_first_name" >
    <% } else { %>
        <input type="text" name="student_first_name" value="<%=Bean.getStudent_first_name()%>">
    <%  } %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

### SECOND.JSP

```
<jsp:useBean id="Bean" scope="session" class="Bean.Student_Enrollment_Bean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="Bean" property="*"/>

<tr> 
    <td >SSLC Name</td>
    <td>
    <% if( (Bean.getName_sslc()==null) || (Bean.getName_sslc().trim().length()==0) || Bean.getName_sslc().equals("null"))  {  %>
        <input type="text" name="name_sslc">
    <% } else { %>
        <input type="text" name="name_sslc" value="<%=Bean.getName_sslc()%>">
    <%  } %>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

### JAVABEAN.JAVA

```
public class Student_Enrollment_Bean 
{

    private String student_first_name="";
    private String name_sslc;


    public String getStudent_first_name() {
        return student_first_name;
    }

    public void setStudent_first_name(String student_first_name) {
        this.student_first_name = student_first_name;
    }


    public String getName_sslc() {
        return name_sslc;
    }

    public void setName_sslc(String name_sslc) {
        this.name_sslc = name_sslc;
    }

}
```

Hi all above is my code.....i have problem with jsp session scope.....In first page i enter name as "first name" then i am going to second page, in this page i 
enter school name as "school name"....now i am going back to first page, in this(first) page the value("first name") is there in the text box what i typed...now i delete the value and i left that 
text field as blank and i am going to second page and then return to first page...here now i want the blank text field only....but it showing the value("first name") what i typed at first time.
Pls Let me know what and where is the problem behind that code.

I dont want the logic by setting as a hidden variables or session.setAttribute. Pls Suggests me any other solution. Why the bean didnot get the value of empty string....?

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

You only use **input** tags in both pages without actually using a **form** tag to define clearly an action that your application should take whenever a user fills the textfields.

My advice would be to search google for how to use JSP and forms. Your JSP pages do not need to have **if** scriptlets as your solution shows.

See for example http://www.jsptut.com/Forms.jsp

Answer (score 0):

The functional requirements are quite unclear, so I can't give a well suited answer.

But I can see that you've declared the `jsp:useBean` yourself to use the session scope. That's the actual problem. You seem to want to keep the data request scoped. In this case just change scope to `request`. You're already using `jsp:setProperty` with `property="*"`, this would automagically put the request parameters in the bean based on the property names. Just make use of it wisely. Further on I would recommend to use [Expression Language](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) instead of those afwul scriptlets.

E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="student_first_name" value="${Bean.student_first_name}">
```

and then in the second.jsp pass it through as hidden parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="student_first_name" value="${Bean.student_first_name}">
```

That's all. And no, it won't print `null` when the actual value is null. That's the nice thing of EL.

That said, I would recommend to drop those PHP/C naming conventions and use real [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html). Variables shouldn't start with uppercase and you should use CamelCase.